# Inner product of an infinite sum

Tags: complex-analysis

For complex numbers $a_{n}, b_{n}$, what would be the next step to simplify this expression:

$$\left \|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} b_{n}\right \|^{2}=\left \langle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}b_{n},\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{m}b_{m}\right \rangle$$

Is it $=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty |a_{n}|^{2}|b_{m}|^{2}$ !?

where $|a_{n}|^{2}=a_{n}\overline{a_{n}}$

Comment: When you say "Is it = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n}|^{2}|b_{n}|^{2}$", the two sums should use different indices.

Comment: Right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it some this way: 
$$\left \langle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}b_{n},\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{m}b_{m}\right \rangle=\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M\to \infty} \left \langle \sum_{n=1}^N a_{n}b_{n},\sum_{m=1}^M a_{m}b_{m}\right \rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^M \left \langle a_{n}b_{n}, a_{m}b_{m}\right \rangle$$ $$ = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left \langle a_{n}b_{n}, a_{m}b_{m}\right \rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{n}b_{n} \overline{a_{m}b_{m}}$$

There are some details in between that I didn't want to type, and I'm a little iffy about the convergence, but I think it works.  You can pass the limit outside the inner product because inner products are continuous.  Your expression is missing the cross terms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can simplify it any further.  Your simplification does not work because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty |a_{n}|^{2}|b_{m}|^{2}$ is actually an upper bound for your expression.  To see this, test the example $1*1 + 1*(-1) + \cdots = 0$.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is an upper bound?

Comment: @Approximist, use Cauchy Schwarz.